# Regex. Python. Keep one group and replace others in string

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: p = 'zxc(.*?)!(.*?)zxc'

In [3]: s = 'zxc wololo ! ololo zxc'

In [4]: re.sub(pattern=p, repl=r"", string=s)
Out[4]: ''

In [5]: re.sub(pattern=p, repl=r"\1", string=s)
Out[5]: ' wololo '
```

**Expected**

```
zxc wololo !zxc
```

**Question**

How to achieve the expected output?

I need to keep 1-st group with "prefix" and "suffix" of pattern. And let's assume that there are more then 2 groups.

Which keyword I should use in `repl` to achieve the expected result?

Comment: `repl=r"zxc \1 !zxc"`? See https://ideone.com/QbJ74Q and https://regex101.com/r/tzlx00/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a zero width lookaround based regex:

```
>>> s = 'zxc wololo ! ololo zxc'
>>> print re.sub(r'(?<=zxc)([^!]*!).*?(?=zxc)', r'\1', s)
zxc wololo !zxc
```

Here:

- `(?<=zxc)` is a lookbehind assertion
- `(?=zxc)` is a lookahead assertion
- `([^!]*!)` matches and captures substring until `!` and following `!` in group #1